# Why is the trace norm of a hermitian matrix equal to the sum of its absolute eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, trace, hermitian-matrices

The trace norm of a matrix $A$ is defined as
$$
||A||_1 \doteq \text{Tr} \sqrt{AA^{\dagger}},
$$
thus, if $A$ is hermitian, we yield
$$
||A||_1=\text{Tr} \sqrt{AA^{\dagger}} = \text{Tr} \sqrt{AA} =\text{Tr} \sqrt{D \Lambda D^{-1} D \Lambda D^{-1}} = \text{Tr} \sqrt{D \Lambda \Lambda D^{-1}} = \text{Tr} \sqrt{\Lambda^2},
$$
where I’ve used the trace cyclic property and $\Lambda=\text{diag}(a_1,\cdots,a_N)$. Shouldn’t
$$
\text{Tr} \sqrt{\Lambda^2} = \sum_i \pm|a_i| \quad \text{instead of} \quad \text{Tr}\sqrt{\Lambda^2}=\sum_i|a_i| \quad \text{?}
$$

Or am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: it's not clear exactly what you are asking... your title is *"Why is the trace norm of a hermitian matrix equal to the sum of its eigenvalues"* which is wrong.  The "trace norm" aka Schatten 1 norm is equal to the sum of the modulus of each eigenvalue.

Comment: I edited that. I am asking why is it like that, or better, why is $\text{Tr}\sqrt{AA^{\dagger}}$ equal to that. Bonus: is the matrix square root associatice?

Comment: if A is Hermtian, its eignevalues are real and $|a| = \sqrt{a^2}$ in the real numbers.

Comment: @Doug M, doesn't the square root of a $\mathbb{R}$-number always have a positive and a negative answer? i.e. $a=-2$ then $\sqrt{(-2)^2}=\sqrt{4}=\pm 2$?

Comment: @FriendlyLagrangian Yes, but the square root of a matrix (as in $\sqrt{AA^\dagger}$) is defined such that the resulting eigenvalues are positive. In other words, this is effectively a "principal" square root

Comment: No.  The square root bracket means to always choose the principal (or in this case positive) root.  If you have the problem $x^2 - 4 = 0$ then yes, there are two roots.  But that is not the same thing as $x = \sqrt 4$ which is why you need to write that $\pm$ in front of the radical.

Comment: @FriendlyLagrangian For a Hermitian positive semidefinite matrix $M$, $P = \sqrt{M}$ is defined to be the unique **positive semidefinite** matrix for which $P^2 = M$

Comment: @Ben Grossman, I see, so we take it to be the positive square root by definition. Thanks, what a subtle remark.